# File In Storage Bucket looses "Share publicly" permission after automated build

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-iam

I'm a bit new to Google Cloud and am using a storage bucket to host a static website.

I've integrated automated builds via a build trigger when my master branch gets updated. I'm successfully able to see the changes when I push to GitHub, but when a preexisting file such as index.html gets updated, the file looses the permission to "Share publicly"

I've followed the tutorial below with the only difference being you the object permissions are now handled at the individual file level on the platform rather then a the top level for the bucket.

https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/automated-publishing-container-builder

This is my cloudbuild.yaml file

```
steps:
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil
    args: ["-m", "rsync", "-r", "-c", "-d", ".", "gs://www.mysite.com"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't configure at the bucket level to have all objects in that bucket publicly readable by default, you'll need to re-apply the permission to the newly uploaded file.

If you know all your updated files need to be set as publicly readable, you can use the -a option with your rsync command and use the canned_acl named "public-read". Your cloudbuild.yaml file would look like this:

```
steps:
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil
    args: ["-m", "rsync", "-a", "public-read", "-r", "-c", "-d", ".", "gs://www.mysite.com"]
```

If you don't want to set all object publicly readable at once, you'll need to set permissions on a per object basis by listing objects and applying permissions with the following command:

```
gsutil acl ch -u AllUsers:R gs://nameBucket/dir/namefile.ext
```

Comment: Thank you. This works!. I added it into my cloudbuild file as an additional step just so I can get more granual and not share the whole repo.